# JS - Require & child-process

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, child-process

I wanted to make a command from my code so I created a js file and started testing. I only want to do a "dir" (ls but on windows).
I have this in my functions.js:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    const { exec } = require('node:child_process');
    exec('"dir"', (stdout, stderr, err)=>{
        console.log(stdout, stderr, err)
    });
}, 1000);
```

But it didn't work and I have this error popping up:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "node:child_process" has not been loaded
> yet for context: _. Use require([])
> https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

I think I'm understanding why this isn't working but I don't know how to make it work. Can somebody explain it to me please?

EDIT

I  still have this problem but I'm going forward...
Now, in my console I have:
'Échec du chargement pour le module dont la source est « node:child_process ».'

while my code is :

```
import { exec } from 'node:child_process';
```

And my function looks like this:

```
let first = true;
const timer = 60000;    //in milliseconds

/**
 * Make a command prompt and write in it the command for checking if there are sessions which need to be deleted.
*/
function deleteOverSessions(){
    console.log(first);
    exec('echo %cd%');
    if(first){
        exec('cd ../../..');
        first = false;
    }

    exec('symfony console session:check-and-delete-finished-ones', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
    
        if (stderr) {
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }

        console.log(`stdout:\n${stdout}`);
    });  
}
```

PS: It works if I start the script in a terminal but not if I launch the page in a browser

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. Do you have a question? Is _"Can somebody explain it to me please ?"_ your actual question? If yes, the answer is: Yes, somebody can explain it to you.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited with a question

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve. You can't import Node.js modules in a browser. You can't run executables in a browser. You're getting an error message, because you're trying to do something that's not possible.

Comment: Yes, @jabaa . This is what Quentin also explained to me. I've found another method to do what I want without using this mechanism so everything is now good. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the `require` function provided by [Require.js](https://requirejs.org/) with the `require` function provided in [CommonJS modules for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

While they are both tools for loading modules, they are tools for loading different kinds of modules.

The [`node:child_process` module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) is built into Node.js and is not available in web browsers (which, for hopefully obvious security reasons,  have no features for running arbitrary executables on the user's computer!)

Comment: Ok, I see @Quentin . So, what can I do? Because my goal is to compare a new Datetime(now) with a DateTime from my database. I did my application with Symfony this is why I need it to work in a web browser ^^. If this is impossible (It should be as you said), do I need to create a new js function working next to my project ?

Comment: I have no idea why you think you need to spawn a child process in order to achieve that. (You can't access your server side database from the browser anything, make an HTTP request and handle it in PHP).

Comment: I found this solution by searching how to do what I want using PHP and I didn't find solutions so now I try using js. But apparently, you're telling me that I can do it with PHP. I don't see how honestly, can you show me, please?

Comment: If I was not clear, you can check; https://gist.github.com/amirkheirabadi73/9342420
And the answer of CommandString made me think to use JS
--> I'll search how to do it with AJAX

Comment: I just edited my post if you're still her to help me please ^^

Comment: Your edit shows that you are trying different ways to persuade `node:child_process` to run in a browser. I refer you to the last paragraph of my answer.